# how to append a zero character at the end of wide char array to make this strange PCZZWSTR winapi data type?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need this to move a file to recycle bin by using `SHFileOperation` function and `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure.
Is this way safe ? ( I'm starting from wide char string object.)

```
wstring wstr = L"my test"
wstr += L'\0'
wchar_t* = wstr.c_str();
```

and since I've added zero in string object and conversion to c-string added another it should be valid PCZZWSTR... but... if there is some 'clever' code along the way sensing that the zero is already at the end ?

Comment: A C string is a contiguous block of characters where the last char is `0`.  A "double-nul terminated" (a bit of a misnomer IMO) is a contiguous block of C strings terminated by the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you showed will work.  You are adding an explicit null character to the end of the wstring's data, and then `c_str()` will return a pointer that is terminated by a second null terminator, thus satisfying the `SHFileOperation()` requirement.